# Set scroll positon of dropdown window of List Navigation Mode?

Tags: android, navigation, android-actionbar, android-spinner

I'm using `ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST` and I have a custom adapter for the `Spinner`.

I've been managed to do everything I needed but there's only one missing thing I can't figure out..

When an item is selected, the next time the DropDown is displayed, the previously selected options is the first one selected. I want the DropDown to display the first item from the list instead.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Call `setSelectedNavigationItem()` on the `ActionBar`. While there are issues with this when you get the `Spinner` in some orientations with `NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS`, it should work fine for `NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST`.

Comment: This approach has a problem.. If I do setSelectedNavigationItem(0), when the first item is touched, it doesn't call onNavigationItemSelected() because it is the same item as currently selected.
To solve this I've inserted a void element as first element, which does the trick, but I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this..

Comment: @sergi: "when the first item is touched, it doesn't call onNavigationItemSelected() because it is the same item as currently selected" -- so? Your UI already is showing the relevant content for the first item. Otherwise, your UI has bugs that desperately need to be fixed. What is shown in the action bar navigation *always* needs to match what the rest of the UI is showing.

Comment: That's not entirely true.. Look at Gmail app.. The first element doesn't have to match the one visible in the Action Bar.

Comment: @sergi: "Look at Gmail app" -- I do every day. The first element always matches what is being viewed in the list. "The first element doesn't have to match the one visible in the Action Bar" -- you are certainly welcome to your opinion.

Comment: Maybe we are not understanding each other, but in Gmail app, if you select the Sent folder, you'll see Sent in the title and Inbox as the first item in the DropDown view..

Comment: @sergi: In the Gmail app, if you select the Sent folder via the action bar `Spinner`, you see "Sent" in the action bar `Spinner` and the sent items in the list.

Comment: @sergi: OK, we are talking about two different things. Rolling all the way back... "when the first item is touched, it doesn't call onNavigationItemSelected() because it is the same item as currently selected" -- so? In this case, the selected item ("Enviats") in your screen shot will be the same as the first item in the drop-down, because that is what `setSelectedNavigationItem(0)` does. You do not need to know if the user clicks on "Enviats", because they are already *on* "Enviats".

Comment: Yeah, in this example you are right, but in my particular case, the first element is more like an action that could be in the menu but instead I use the navigation list because, in this particular case, makes more sense.
It's like in Gmail app the entry "Show all labels" could be placed in the menu and would make sense, but it makes more sense to place in the navigation list.

Comment: @sergi: You are certainly welcome to do that. Simply make it be something other than the first item in the list. For example, "in Gmail app the entry 'Show all labels'" is not the first item in the list. You will also note that 'Show all labels' leads the user to another activity (at least in the phone version of the app), one which does not use list navigation, which further insulates them from the sort of problems you are encountering.